# Split column into multiple columns by index

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to split a character column (containing lots of information of lots of variables without any type of separator character). I have a vector containing the number of characters correspondent to each variable as well as the new column names. I've tried:

```
for(i in seq(1:length(widths)-1)){
  var_name <- colnames[i]
  ficheiro%>%
    mutate({{var_name}}, substr(ficheiro$data,start,widths[i]+start))->ficheiro
  start <- start+widths[i]
}
```

where,

- widths represents the vector containing the number of characters correspondent to each variable
- ficheiro is the data file with 1 column to be transformed
- colnames is the vector containing the column names to be created

I was expecting a final "ficheiro" file with all the new columns created.

Comment: Have you tried the `separate_wider_position` function from the `tidyr` package. Seems to do exactly what you're explaining.

Comment: I was on github looking for that function within the tidyr package but it seems like it isn't there, probably due an update in the package. Nevertheless I´m working on making this work using the separate() function. Thank you for the reply and tentative to help @Harrison Jones :D

Comment: If you download tidyr from CRAN you should have `separate_wider_position` available. I don't think I bothered to download an unreleased version from Github. Either way, `separate` should work too, it was just superseded by `separate_wider_position`

Comment: Yes, indeed I eventually managed to work separate() out and have what I want. Thank you  :)